# How to resolve "Can inject only one of <ITestContext, XmlTest> into a @AfterTest" exception

Tags: java, selenium, testng

```
@AfterTest
public void applicationTearDown(ITestResult it)
{
    if(it.getStatus()==1)
    {
        pass++;
    }
    else if(it.getStatus() == 2)
    {
        String name = it.getName();
        Utils.takeSnapshot(driver, PHOTO_PATH+name+".png");
        fail++;
    }
    else if(it.getStatus() == 3)
    {
        skip++;
    }
    driver.quit();
}
```

While running its throwing

```
org.testng.TestNGException: Can inject only one of <ITestContext, XmlTest> into a @AfterTest annotated applicationTearDown
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you share @BeforeTest method?

Answer (score 0):

From the code, it seems like you want to run your `applicationTearDown` after each test method has been executed. You need to use `@AfterMethod` and **NOT** `@AfterTest`.

`@AfterTest`/`@BeforeTest` are used to execute a method after/before all/any test methods have been executed. So `ITestResult` cannot be injected into such methods, because `ITestResult` holds the information of a single test method execution.

So, you need to use `@AfterMethod`/`@BeforeMethod`. These are the only methods which would accept an `ITestResult` as parameter.